# How to share OpenGL 3.3+ functions and context between files in a Qt 5.4 program

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opengl, opengl-es

Currently trying to port an SDL2 / GLEW OpenGL 3.3 program to Qt to make use of the GUI tools, however since I actually need to use the window space, I can't just inherit from QOpenGLWindow. I have to initialize a new widget then add it to the window using a QVBoxLayout widget as such:

```
//in oglWidget.hpp file
class OGLWidget : public QOpenGLWidget, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  bool m_core;
  bool mTest;

public slots:
  void cleanup();

public:
  OGLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~OGLWidget();

  QSize minimumSizeHint() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  QSize sizeHint() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

  void initializeGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  void paintGL() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  void resizeGL(int width, int height) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
  void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

//inside mainWindow.cpp
...
  QSurfaceFormat format;
  format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
  format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
  format.setVersion(3, 2);
  format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

  glRenderer = new OGLWidget();
  glRenderer->setFormat(format);
  ui->openglLayout->addWidget(glRenderer);
...
//in oglWidget.cpp
void OGLWidget::initializeGL() 
{
  //from parent class
  this->initializeOpenGLFunctions();

  //deals with unexpected closeings due to foreign widgets etc
  connect(context(), &QOpenGLContext::aboutToBeDestroyed, this, &OGLWidget::cleanup);

  QString versionString(QLatin1String(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(glGetString(GL_VERSION))));
  qDebug() << "Driver Version String:" << versionString;
  qDebug() << "Current Context:" << this->format();
}
```

This allows me to use the OpenGL API as it is, simply calling it when I need it. The problem is that I can't seem to share this between files, for example a resource manager class that is purely static, or even a shader manager class that is not static. I can only access OpenGL from this odlWidget.cpp file. I can't seem to figure out how to give access to other files since GLEW just needs to be included anywhere that requires access.

The following produces a segFault:

```
//in shadermanager.hpp
class ShaderManager
{
private:
  void checkForErrors(GLuint object, std::string type);
  QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core *glFuncs;
public:
  GLuint ID;
  ShaderManager() {glFuncs->initializeOpenGLFunctions();}
}
```

What does Qt require to be able to share the OpenGL API? The context? Do I have to pass the current QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core object to the objects that must have access to OpenGL every time? The documentation on this (including the examples) simply use a single file for all OpenGL related functions and the only one that doesn't (the boxes example) adds a commented include to GLEW.

What is the best approach to this problem?

I'm running Xubuntu LTS 64 bits, I can confirm drivers and libraries are correctly installed since the SDL2 / GLEW version compiles and runs normally.

Comment: Make sure your `ShaderManager` is being created after you have an OpenGL context (don't know QT, so I'm guessing after `initializeGL`). Also, reloading the GL functions in `ShaderMAnager` is redundant if you do it in `initializeGL`.

Comment: It is, still won't compile. EDIT: My bad, It compiles it just segfaults.

Comment: It won't compile? You said it segfaulted. What's the compiler error and source code? Also you don't initialize `ShaderManager.glFuncs` in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, after many headaches I came up with 2 viable solutions, posting them in case someone needs help since there is a lack of resources about this specific situation.

NOTE: This was tested on QT 5.4 for linux / xubuntu LTS.

If you need to share the same context among files (not widgets) that require opengl functions you can either:

### 1. Use GLEW to manage the opengl functions available.

Specify the context and surface settings (you can do this in a parent widget or even in the main.cpp file itself).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QSurfaceFormat format;
  format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
  format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
  format.setVersion(3, 2);
  format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
  //here qt will set this as the default format for the rest of the app
  //and will use it to implicitly initialize any object that requires one
  QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

After you have a valid context, initialize GLEW.

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
//inside a class that inherits from QOpenGLWidget
//if you rather not inherit, you have to instance a QtOpenGLContext yourself
  this->makeCurrent();
  glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
  GLenum glew_status = glewInit();
  if(glew_status != GLEW_OK)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glew_status));
    }
```

Then, whenever you require access to the opengl API simply add the following code the header file.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#define QT_NO_OPENGL_ES_2
```

However, due to rather recent changes to Qt, using GLEW will ONLY WORK IF YOU COMPILE QT YOURSELF WITH THE -opengl desktop CONFIGURATION. If you don't it will still work with severe bugs (which is the reason the thread was created), if you check for errors, opengl error 1280 will pop, this is because by default, Qt's opengl implementation is that of openglES, and it will clash with GLEW.

### 2. Use Qt's opengl wrappers

This is rather simpler, and seems to work so far. Simply include the desired qtopengl functions (note that as of 5.2 or so there are quite a few different headers each with their own version) or simply use QOpenglFunctions.

Then, every time you require access to the API, simple include an instance of the function objects and access opengl through said object.

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>

...

    QOpenGLFunctions *glFuncs = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
    glFuncs->glCompileShader(example);
```

Note that you still need a valid context, it can be created in the same manner that the one in the GLEW example was.

Hope it helps.